# Upgrade database trigger to 2nd generation Cloud Function atomically

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Say that I have implemented two triggers that listen for created and deleted users in the Realtime Database to keep track of the amount of users:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions"
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"

admin.initializeApp()
const db = admin.database()

const userRef = functions.runWith({failurePolicy: true}).database.ref("users/{userId}")
export const onUserCreate = userRef.onCreate(() =>
  db.ref("nUsers").set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1)))
export const onUserDelete = userRef.onDelete(() =>
  db.ref("nUsers").set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(-1)))
```

My understanding is that since these functions are guaranteed to trigger exactly once, with the `failurePolicy` enabled this will result in an eventually consistent count, even if events happen out of order.

But what if I want to upgrade my app to the 2nd generation Cloud Functions? If the new function is deployed first, there is a risk that users will be counted twice. If the old function is removed first there is a risk that users will not be counted at all. Is there a way to remove one function and add another one as a single atomic operation?

I can think of two other solutions:

1. Make the count operations idempotent. I just cannot think of a way to make this specific operation idemponent, with the limited transaction support the RTDB has.
2. Accept that the count will be wrong, and run a script to correct the count once the migration to gen 2 has completed. This could be hard if users are often added or removed though.

Any better solutions?

Comment: Idempotence is already a best practice for Cloud Functions, regardless of anything else you need to do. Minimally this involves making sure that the same event doesn't take effect twice. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions

Comment: @DougStevenson That post mostly talks about using the event id as idempotency key. That's not possible here, since I assume the gen2 version will have a different event id. The user id would be another possible idempotency key, but that does not work if users are created and added several times (the id is just the Firebase Auth user id, so it would be reused).

Comment: You don't have to assume - you can try it yourself.  Create a project with both types of functions and see if they trigger with the same ID or not. If they aren't the same, you could synthesize your own unique ID using a hash of each event using the payload of data that doesn't change.

Comment: Can confirm the two event systems do produce different event ids. I don't think this is solvable without changing the user data structure or the counting algorithm. In this sequence:
[1. Alice is created,
2. Alice is removed,
3. Alice is created]
there is no way to distinguish between event 1 and 3. Yet I want the count to be increased both times. This works with just one function because the trigger itself only happens once, but with gen2 as well, it's not possible.

Comment: You could add some random string to each payload and use that to ensure the hash is unique for every event.

Comment: That would be an option, just assign a random string to the user when it is created. It seems like the event timestamp is at least identical for gen1 and gen2, so maybe "User X deleted at time Y" is unique enough. I was staring myself a bit blind on trying to make a perfect solution, but I think this boils down to the two generals' problem, so an exact solution is probably impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having completed this migration, I'll try to provide what the answer actually is.

My question is a bit misdirected, since it assumes that there's a responsibility on Google Cloud to provide this atomic operation. There is not. The assumption was based on official samples like [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/child-count), which uses the same counter implementation.

This is misleading, since this is not actually a good implementation if you need a consistent count. There's many ways your function could be called multiple times, including switching to 2nd gen, renaming your function or moving it to another region. What you need to do instead, is find a way to ensure idempotency on your own. [This blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions) is a good source of inspiration. Note though that using the event id as described there does not work, as it is different between 1st gen and 2nd gen Cloud Functions.

In my case, I was able to implement a lease system, where the unique token is a hash of the user id and the timestamp of the creation or deletion. The timestamp does appear to be consistent between 1st gen and 2nd gen. Depending on how your data is structured, there may be a better way to solve it in your case.